# Python sklearn LogisticRegression ValueError: invalid __array_struct__

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas

I want to run a Logistic Regression to predict the genre of the movies in this data set: [movies.csv](https://tumde-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/alexander_farr_tum_de/EauYmDrHzclOiKghjUqjZsQBHKjbJj-zdnWlH7fgA1BDjg?e=bhLaFD)

This is the code I use:

```
from datascience import *
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np

movies = Table.read_table('movies.csv')
features=["marri", "huh", "hous", "mother", "nice", "home", "miss", "play", "happi", "write","power", "captain", "ship", "weve", "move", "ship", "system", "world", "command", "three"]
training_proportion = 17/20
num_movies = movies.num_rows
num_train = int(num_movies * training_proportion)
num_test = num_movies - num_train

train_movies = movies.take(np.arange(num_train))
test_movies = movies.take(np.arange(num_train, num_movies))
train_20 = train_movies.select(features)
test_20 = test_movies.select(features)

model = LogisticRegression()
## The target column is the genre
predicted_genre=movies.column("Genre")
model.fit(train_20, predicted_genre)
predicted_classes = model.predict(predicted_genre)
accuracy = accuracy_score(predicted_genre.flatten(),predicted_classes)
parameters = model.coef_
parameters
```

However, this code throws following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-95d9b3b0fe68> in <module>
     19 ## The target column is the genre
     20 predicted_genre=movies.column("Genre")
---> 21 model.fit(train_20, predicted_genre)
     22 predicted_classes = model.predict(predicted_genre)
     23 accuracy = accuracy_score(predicted_genre.flatten(),predicted_classes)

/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1530 
   1531         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=_dtype, order="C",
-> 1532                          accept_large_sparse=solver != 'liblinear')
   1533         check_classification_targets(y)
   1534         self.classes_ = np.unique(y)

/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    717                     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
    718                     warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype,
--> 719                     estimator=estimator)
    720     if multi_output:
    721         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    494             try:
    495                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 496                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    497             except ComplexWarning:
    498                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: invalid __array_struct__
```

Additionally, there is the following warning:

```
/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py:432: FutureWarning: Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22. Specify a solver to silence this warning.
  FutureWarning)
/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datascience/tables.py:193: FutureWarning: Implicit column method lookup is deprecated.
  warnings.warn("Implicit column method lookup is deprecated.", FutureWarning)
/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datascience/tables.py:193: FutureWarning: Implicit column method lookup is deprecated.
  warnings.warn("Implicit column method lookup is deprecated.", FutureWarning)
```

How would I need to change the code to get it working?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the datascience module? Is that pandas? Sounds like the type of the value predicted_genre=movies.column("Genre") is not an array, sounds like a pandas Series?

Comment: No, its a module by UC Berkeley (http://data8.org/datascience/) which could also be achieved with pandas. In the documentation (also see: http://data8.org/sp20/python-reference.html) it says that table.column() returns an array so that should be fine